# QtCustomPlot is plotting different times that what im passing in

Tags: c++, qt

I am trying to pass in time values on a range of a single day(9:30 - 4:00), i use an api and libcurl to retrieve a .json for me that gives me "date: 2020-06-04" and "minute: 09:30" and i have them read into a vector like so:

```
//Reads in data from json(historical data 1 day delayed)
    for(Json::Value::ArrayIndex i = 0 ; i != chartData.size(); i++)
    {
        if(chartData[i].isMember("average"))
        {
            value.push_back(chartData[i]["average"].asDouble());

            time.push_back(chartData[i]["date"].asString());
            auto timeDate = QDate::fromString(time[i].c_str(), Qt::ISODate);

            minute.push_back(chartData[i]["minute"].asString());
            auto minuteDate = QTime::fromString(minute[i].c_str(), "hh:mm");

            timeInEpoch.push_back(QDateTime(timeDate, minuteDate).toSecsSinceEpoch());


            if((value[i] == 0) && (i != chartData.size() - 1))
            {
                value[i] = value[i-1];
            }

            if(value[i] > maxAvg)
            {
                maxAvg = value[i];
            }

            else if(value[i] < minAvg)
            {
                minAvg = value[i];

            }
        }
    }
```

I then have them converted to a date and time so they should be like "2020-06-04 09:30" and then converted into SecsSinceEpoch().

After that they should be plotted but when they are plotted its like all of the times are shifted hours to the right, like so[image: image of graph]

Does anyone have any ideas what would be causing this? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

`fromString()` will give back you the datetime in local time, while `toSecsSinceEpoch()` is converting the datetime value to UTC. So either you have to set specifically the timezone of the input string (for example to UTC), or you can use  `offsetFromUtc()` (https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdatetime.html#offsetFromUtc) to adjust the result of `toSecsSinceEpoch()`

Comment: Ahhhh that makes sense, is there a way to set it to convert it to whatever the users current time zone is?

Comment: You can use for example `offsetFromUtc()` https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdatetime.html#offsetFromUtc